# jquery mobile select menu doesn´t fire onchange event on safari mobile?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I´m using jquery mobile and trying to use the select menu form in a way that would allow me once I select an option to go to a specific part of my html page. Here is the code snippet I have but it doesn´t seem to work on safari nor safari mobile.

```
<select id="mymenu">
<option value="">Select a site</option>
<option value="#page1">Page1</option>
<option value="#page2">Page2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu");
selectmenu.onchange=function(){ 
 var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex];
 if (chosenoption.value!="nothing"){
  window.open(chosenoption.value, "", ""); 
 }
}

</script>
```

Would you say that I should use another event?

Comment: Your code contains many errors. There's not even 1 semicolon after instructions.

Comment: Sorry for the errors. I will correct the post.